# Calling socket->native_handle() from another thread

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, posix, boost-asio

I'm writing some asio/tcp server and would like to map native socket descriptor with tcp session identifier.
I'm writing id getter like:

```
inline int get_session_id() { return socket_.native_handle(); }
```

And calling from second (packets dispatching thread) thread like:

```
cout << session_shared_ptr->get_session_id() << endl;
```

and it writes valid id only for first time, so I guess to something in my implementation is bad.

Can anyone advice me where I did mistake?

Comment: When you say "first time" I assume you do some things between the times where you do the output statement? Does it work well if you do two output statements just next to each other? What happens between the first and the second output in your code? What happens with the connection between the two outputs?

Comment: Server received two messages, pass pair<session_shared_ptr,message_shared_ptr> to queue and second thread to awaken and parse message; 
message parsing is ok, session ptr is valid too, but session id not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, using the native handle as a session id strikes me as a fantasticically bad idea.

Not only did you pick an implementation defined backdoor, but also you picked one that is not portable - so your code risks getting different semantics across platforms.

Remember, these are the underlying handles  of an abstraction. The abstractions exist for a reason! Who knows, if your network gets reconnected the native handle may change. Nowhere is it documented that you can retain the handle and rely on it to identify the API object.

---

Of course when you do multi threading, you have to keep in mind everything you always do when threading:

- synchronize access to shared state and resources
- coordinate the lifetime of such objects
- guard against starvation and dead/soft locks while doing the above

Now, you don't speak about synchronization measures, so you have a data race:

> [Thread Safety](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html#boost_asio.reference.ip__tcp.socket.thread_safety)
>
> Distinct objects: Safe.
>   Shared objects: ***Unsafe***.

The standard specifies a data race as [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior); Anything can happen. You can be thankful your house didn't burn down. Yet.

---

All in all: just use a dependable ID. Generate a UUID and store it in the session. Use the C++ object identity (i.e. *address*) for identification if you know you don't move sessions with equality.

If you must for some useful reason access the socket from another thread, provide synchronization (mutex - mutual exclusion, or by way of posting to the session strand).